# How to refresh a GridView?

Tags: android, xml, gridview, layout

I have a GridView which is pretty similar to the Google tutorial, except that I want to add the ImageViews on runtime (via a subactivity). The results are okay, but the layout of the View is messed up: The GridView doesn't fill the content of its parent, what do I have to do to design it properly?

Here the code of adding the children:

```
public void initializeWorkbench(GridView gv, Vector<String> items) {
        Prototype.workbench.setDimension(screenWidth, divider.height()+workbenchArea.height());
        Prototype.workbench.activateWorkbench();
        // this measures the workbench correctly
        Log.d(Prototype.TAG, "workbench width: "+Prototype.workbench.getMeasuredWidth());
        // 320
        Log.d(Prototype.TAG, "workbench height: "+Prototype.workbench.getMeasuredHeight());
        // 30
        ImageAdapter imgAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this.getContext(), items);
        gv.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
        gv.measure(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        gv.requestLayout();
        gv.forceLayout();
        Log.d(Prototype.TAG, "gv width: "+gv.getMeasuredWidth());
        // 22
        Log.d(Prototype.TAG, "gv height: "+gv.getMeasuredHeight());
        // 119
        Prototype.workbench.setDimension(screenWidth, divider.height()+workbenchArea.height());
    }
}
```

activateWorkbench, setDimension and measure in the workbench (LinearLayout above the GridView):

```
public void activateWorkbench() {
    if(this.equals(Prototype.workbench)) {
        this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        show = true;
        measure();
    }
}

public void setDimension(int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
    this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
    this.invalidate();
}

private void measure() {
    if (this.getOrientation() == LinearLayout.VERTICAL) {
        int h = 0;
        int w = 0;
        this.measureChildren(0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = this.getChildAt(i);
            h += v.getMeasuredHeight();
            w = (w < v.getMeasuredWidth()) ? v.getMeasuredWidth() : w;
        }
        if (this.equals(Prototype.tagarea))
            height = (h < height) ? height : h;
        if (this.equals(Prototype.tagarea))
            width = (w < width) ? width : w;
    }
    this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

The ImageAdapter constructor:

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c, Vector<String> items) {
    mContext = c;

    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        // We can read and write the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        // We can only read the media
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    } else {
        // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but
        // all we need
        // to know is we can neither read nor write
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    }

    if (mExternalStorageAvailable && mExternalStorageWriteable) {
        for (String item : items) {
            File f = new File(item);
            if (f.exists()) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                    bitmaps.add(b);
                    files.add(f);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e(Prototype.TAG, "", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="bottom"

                android:paddingLeft="0px"
                android:paddingTop="0px"
                android:paddingRight="0px">

    <com.unimelb.pt3.ui.TransparentPanel
            android:id="@+id/workbench" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10px"
            android:paddingTop="0px"
            android:paddingLeft="0px"
            android:paddingBottom="0px"
            android:paddingRight="0px">

        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </com.unimelb.pt3.ui.TransparentPanel>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 44):

the GridView has an invalidateViews() method.

when you call this method: "all the views to be rebuilt and redrawn."
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

i think this is what you need:)

Comment: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. When you're refreshing a gridview, you're often doing so because you're retrieving information from the web, in which case this will not be the case.

Comment: This did not force a redrawing of the view for me.

Answer (score 34):

You must, first tell the adapter to notify that the data has changed and set the adapter again to the grid

```
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This worked for me, but with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the first line, while I didn't need the second line. According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html, the first forces the View(s) to refresh. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

This may be helpful.
I refresh a gridview of book image thumbnails after a delete is executed on an item.
Using adapter.notifyDataChanged(); as mentioned above didn't work for me as it's called in my adapter.

```
//this is a call that retrieves cached data.
//your constructor can be designed and used without it.
final Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
```

I essentially just reload the adapter and bind it to the same view.

```
//reload the adapter
adapter = new BooksAdapter(MyBooks.this, MyBooks.this, data, show_collection );
grid.invalidateViews();
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: thank you! your method worked for me. my adapter use random items and for it to re-create them all the time i needed to create a new adapter object. you saved me lots of search time. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

@flyerz @snagnever

Together you guys have got it. It should be:

```
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
grid.invalidateViews();
```

This will flag the adapter that its data has changed, which will then be propagated to the grid whenever after the invalidateViews() method is called.

Glad I found this question because I could not figure out how to add items to the grid after its been rendered.

Answer (score 10):

None of these answers actually worked for me and I had to mash all of them together. To actually get the GridView to update, you need to do this:

```
 adapter.notifyDataChanged();
 grid.invalidateViews();
 grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps anyone who couldn't get the other solutions to work.

Comment: Don't you have to create the a new adapter with the new values?

Comment: I confirm this, and I am awkwardly I use the old adapter since only the data that change, not the whole adapter.

Answer (score 5):

You should not call `invalidateViews` and `setAdapter` to refresh your `grid view`. This is not a good idea to keep your `grid view` updated, if you update in that way it would cost a lot of time and memory.

If you have a chance to look at `getView` method you will see that `convertView` is created just once. When you call `notifyDataChanged`, it will update this view. Whereas if you call `invalidateViews`, previously created views will be recreated. This is not a good solution.

Your `getView` method is called when you call `notifyDataChanged`. So your getView method should look something like the code below.

```java
public List list;

public class SimpleItemViewHolder extends Object
{
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView imageView;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View itemView = convertView;
    SimpleItemViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        viewHolder = (SimpleItemViewHolder)itemView.getTag();

    }else{
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_name, null);
        TextView labelField = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
        labelField.setText(list.get(position).Name);
        //Typeface boldFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Font-Bold.ttf");
        //labelField.setTypeface(boldFont);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        //Bitmap bitmap = init your bitmap here;
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  

        viewHolder = new SimpleItemViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = imageView;
        viewHolder.textView = labelField;
        itemView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }

    //don't create new views, instead use previous ones and update them.
    viewHolder.textView.setText(list.get(position).Name);
    //viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(your_bitmap);  
    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is theory. And what do you do if the Grid don't update its layout on when convertViews change their sizes ?

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin I think it would not make any difference if you change the size of a cell. You just need set layoutparams of the itemView. Also overriding and calling `onMeasure` method of the gridview may help.

Comment: No, it's not working. If an itemView height change over the time, the GridView will not detect the changes, even with an `adapter.notifySetChanges()` or a `gridView.invalidateViews()`. Perhaps it works with `onMeasure` overriding, but I just don't wont to implement a custom GridView just to achieve such a basic behavior...

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin It's all for performance, you can use invalidateViews either, but if you have hundreds of cells in your gridview, you will see that your app hangs up a few seconds when you call invalidateViews. So I recommend you to use onMeasure method.

Comment: Calling `invalidateViews()` doesn't solve the problem... The only working is effectively to manually set height of each sell...

Comment: Why do you need to change the convertViews sizes?

Answer (score 2):

```
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
```

may not works just because data for the adapter is stale (if Activity or fragment was not destroyed and have been sitting in the back stack for instance).

So, if firstly refresh data, then after it will be working.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the `GridView` inside `com.unimelb.pt3.ui.TransparentPanel` which is `10px` tall.

- You shouldn't use `px`, you should use `dp`.
- Change `com.unimelb.pt3.ui.TransparentPanel`'s `android:layout_height="10px"` to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Comment: I changed that, but it doesn't help. The problem is not the height of the GridView, which is placed fullsize in TransparentPanel and has a scrolling bar for oversized content, but the width. This is just 22, although its LayoutParams are fill_parent and the TransparentPanel has a fullsize width of 320. I think I need to update/refresh the layout process, but don't know how to do that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter :

```
class MAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
   List<Objects> mObjects;
...

 public void clearAdapter(){
        mObjects.clear();
    }

 public void addNewValues(List<Objects> mObjects){
        this.mObjects = mObjects;
    }

...

}


adapter.clearAdapter(); // clear old values
adapter.addNewValues(MObjects);
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
```